# General solution of diferential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We can try to find the general solution of the following differential equation:

$2x^3y'+2x^5y^2-7x^3y+14 = 0$

$y'=-x^2y^2+7y/2-7/x^3$

This is a Riccati equation. Then, substitute $y=-v/x^2$. We will obtain the following equation

$v'=v^2+(2/x+7/2)v+7/x$

I couldn't proceed further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your change of function is not the best. See Eqs.(4-5) in :

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html
$$y=\frac{v'}{x^2 v}\quad\implies\quad y'=\frac{v''}{x^2 v}-\frac{(v')^2}{x^2 v^2}-2\frac{v'}{x^3 v}$$
After puting it into $2x^3y'+2x^5y^2-7x^3y+14 = 0$ and simplifying :
$$2x\,v''-(7x+4)v'+14\,v=0$$
This is a second order linear ODE. Solving a linear ODE is generaly simpler than solving a nonlinear ODE even with an increase of order. In the present case there is no difficulty to solve the above second order linear ODE :
$$v=c_1\exp(\frac72x)+c_2\left(7x(7x+4)+8 \right)$$
$$y=\frac{v'}{x^2 v}=\frac{c_1\:\frac72\exp(\frac72x)+c_2 14(7x+2)}{x^2 \left(c_1\exp(\frac72x)+c_2\left(7x(7x+4)+8 \right)\right)}$$
$c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants not both nul.  This is equivalent to only one arbitrary constant $C=c_1/c_2$ or $C=c_2/c_1$.